# Better way to do these MySQL Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Well lets me explain my question:

I got these tables:

### product

- product_id
- product_name

### photo

- photo_url
- product_id

### video

- video_url
- product_id

and i want to do joins to list all photos and videos of a product ... well i can think in 2 way to do it:

First:

```
select b.photo_url,c.video_url from product a left join photo b using(product_id) left join video c using(product_id) where a.product_id=X;
```

or doing two queries like:

```
select b.photo_url from product a left join photo b using(product_id) where a.product_id=X;
select c.video_url from product a left join video c using(product_id) where a.product_id=X;
```

Well the first query looks better but is there a problem if i got 2 video and 3 photos of this product I'll need to parse it with php to don't get repeat records; Anyway I would like to know which these query is better.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a `product_id` column on `video`.  Is that a mistake?

Comment: use a UNION http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: `UNION`... that will be all.

Comment: Unions have to have the same fields in the select, FYI. It looks like that is the case here. Should work.

Comment: yes sry it was a misstake

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any connections between particular videos and particular photos, other than the common product.  Which you say may have multiple of each.  So why not do a union?

```
SELECT photo_url FROM photo WHERE product_id=X
UNION
SELECT video_url FROM video WHERE product_id=X;
```

If you are concerned about distinguishing URL types, then add a column:

```
SELECT photo_url AS url, 'photo' AS url_type FROM photo WHERE product_id=X
UNION
SELECT video_url AS url, 'video' AS url_type FROM video WHERE product_id=X;
```

Comment: well doesn't have any connections between photos and videos but if i do only one query like: select b.photo_url,c.video_url from product a left join photo b using(product_id) left join video c using(product_id) where a.product_id=X; and parse it with php doesn't look better and more fast?